# Using named colors from asset catalogue in IBDesignable Views crashes IB even when specifying the Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uicolor, ibdesignable

When referencing a colour that has been created using `UIColor(named:)` Interface Builder crashes due to it finishing nil for the colour.

Initially I thought this would be as IB was looking for the colour in the wrong bundle but after specifying the Bundle to look in IB could still not find the colour.

This is working fine at runtime on device/simulator.

```
extension UIColor {

    // MARK: - Oranges
    static let tangerine = UIColor(named: "Tangerine", in: Bundle(for: AppDelegate.self), compatibleWith: nil)!
    .....
}
```

Looking into it a bit further the Bundle which IB looks in does seem to contain references to the colours as well as images so you would expect it to work..?

```
po Bundle(for: AppDelegate.self)
NSBundle </Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ddspmruccrhrxhbawgwawhzkrrts/Build/Intermediates.noindex/IBDesignables/Products/Debug - DEV-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app> (loaded)`
```

`xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info pathToAsserts.car`

```
  {
"AssetType" : "Color",
"Color components" : [
  1,
  1,
  1,
  1
],
"Colorspace" : "srgb",
"Idiom" : "universal",
"Name" : "Marmalade",
"Scale" : 1
},
{
"AssetType" : "Image",
"BitsPerComponent" : 8,
"ColorModel" : "RGB",
"Colorspace" : "srgb",
"Compression" : "lzfse",
"Encoding" : "ARGB",
"Idiom" : "universal",
"Image Type" : "kCoreThemeOnePartScale",
"Name" : "sweets",
"Opaque" : false,
"PixelHeight" : 412,
"PixelWidth" : 324,
"RenditionName" : "sweets@2x.png",
"Scale" : 2,
"SizeOnDisk" : 132830
},
```

Edit: Turns out specifying the bundle as above is enough. Cleaning the build folder, deleting derived data and restarting Xcode made it all work as expected

Comment: I think the static context could be a problem. The way IB loads bundles is a bit strange. I remember having the same problem with fonts. I remember using fallback fonts (using `??`).

Comment: Yeah when IB loads the main bundle is not the same main bundle as the app. I would expect it to have access to the apps bundle though and for it to be found by using the UIColor method which takes a bundle?
I did consider using ?? and the having a fallback colour but it's not ideal (e.g if someone deletes a colour by mistake a crash would be preferred so we could spot it before shipping).

Comment: I think that IB loads the code several times, first without bundles and then again with bundles. There is some magic in there. Maybe a `lazy var` or a static getter would work better there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was just Xcode playing up. Cleaning the build folder, derived data and restarting Xcode fixed the issue (when specifying the correct bundle as shown in my code snippet).

Answer (score 3):

One thing I noticed fighting with this: If your fonts are in the main bundle, using `Bundle.main` doesn't work but using `Bundle(for: AppDelegate.self)` (or some other class *in* your main bundle) does.

Probably something to do with the way `IBDesignablesAgent` loads everything into its process, but I definitely did not expect that.