# How to use color sets in designable views in storyboards?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard, ibdesignable

The situation and steps to reliably reproduce:

1. Set up a macOS app project with Swift and storyboards for UI in Xcode.
2. Define an arbitrary color for the "AccentColor" color set in the asset catalogue which is there by default in the Xcode project template.
3. Create a `@IBDesignable` subclass of `NSView` (see [source code here](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/DesignableNamedColors/blob/main/DesignableNamedColors/DesignableView.swift) or further below).
4. Add a custom view from the Xcode library to the default window in the storyboard and set its class to whatever the custom class is named (`DesignableView` in my example case).
5. Set the `@IBDesignable` color property to "AccentColor" in the *attributes inspector* of Xcode.
6. Either refresh the previews manually (see *Editor* menu of Xcode) or wait for the automatic refresh.

**You can find the example project in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/DesignableNamedColors).** The view in question is quite simple (source code copied to here by request):

```swift
import AppKit

@IBDesignable class DesignableView: NSView {
    @IBInspectable var color: NSColor = .clear
}
```

Observations:

1. It works fine with *system colors*.
2. Picking color sets from the asset catalogue also is not a problem in case of *predefined views*.

Problem:

As soon as I pick a color from the asset catalogue (in this case "AccentColor" but the name does not matter), the custom view preview in the storyboard crashes with the following error:

> The agent raised a "NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException" exception: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (IBICDynamicCocoaColor) for key (NSColor) because no class named "IBICDynamicCocoaColor" was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target). If the class was renamed, use setClassName:forClass: to add a class translation mapping to NSKeyedUnarchiver

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

How can I fix that? The error message does not help me.

Comment: I have [another code branch](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/DesignableNamedColors/tree/Debugging-IBDesignablesAgent) in which I attempt to load the named color from the asset catalogue in the code of my custom view. It works when running the app but not in the storyboard preview or better said `IBDesignablesAgent`.

Comment: I found a workaround for colors which are not set through `@IBInspectable` properties but in code with [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092237/769502). The correct bundle for named color must be specified explicitly.

Comment: Post your code (a [mre]) in the question please.

Comment: @Willeke How about the already linked GitHub repository which poses a complete reproducible example? I copied and added the view code anyway. Plain code is not enough in this case because it also involves a storyboard (740 lines here which usually are not edited by hand) and the Xcode interface builder (see screenshot).

Comment: What you're trying to do is probably impossible. Looking up a color in the asset catalog is something that happens in code at runtime; the IBDesignable engine knows nothing about it.

Comment: @matt Looking up colors programmatically in the asset catalogue in the IBDesignable agent works as written in my second comment above and [proven in the example project](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/DesignableNamedColors/commit/214d09815a09102d1317a462f1e4678911567c75). It boils down to `NSColor(named: "AccentColor", bundle: bundle)`. I see it as only a workaround, though. By the way: The IBDesignable agent can even be debugged from Xcode. The debug button is revealed in case of error.